# How add event listeners dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, event-handling, jquery-events

I have some code (jQuery):

```
$(document).on('tap', '#category1-btn', {category : "category1"}, onlineListGen);
$(document).on('tap', '#category2-btn', {category : "category2"}, onlineListGen);
$(document).on('tap', '#category3-btn', {category : "category3"}, onlineListGen);
$(document).on('tap', '#category4-btn', {category : "category4"}, onlineListGen);
$(document).on('tap', '#category5-btn', {category : "category5"}, onlineListGen);
$(document).on('tap', '#category6-btn', {category : "category6"}, onlineListGen);
```

This seems to violate the DNRY rule. What's more, the number of categories is dependent on a JSON file that is read, and in future, I want to dynamically create the categoryN-btn(s) depending on the JSON file contents. AS such is there a way to do the above with either dynamically generating the event listeners or somehow doing it with classes?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop :

```
var count = N; //N is the count of button from JSON

for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
     $(document).on('tap', '#category'+i+'-btn', {category : "category"+i}, onlineListGen);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap one of those in a function, and just call it whenever.

```
var tapper = (function(){
  var c = 0;
  return function(){
    $(document).on('tap', '#category'+(++c)+'-btn', {category : 'category'+c}, onlineListGen);
    return $;
  }
})();
tapper(); tapper(); // call whenever and wherever
```

Comment: Having methods which work by global state and modify the global state as side-effect doesn't seem like a well maintainable solution.

Answer (score 1):

As always the idea came to me just after I posted here.

I simply added this to my event handler function

```
function myFunction(){
  var category = this.id.slice(0,-4); //the slice removes the '-btn' from the ID
  myData = JSONData[category]
  //some more code that uses myData
}
```

and used the event listener

```
$(document).on('tap', '.category-btn', myFunction);
```

where the html for the button is

```
<a href="#category-1" class="category-btn" id= "category1-btn">category</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know what element type these categories are, you can add a handler which works generically (assuming a `button` for the element with has the `#categoryX-btn` ID - adjust to match your markup):

```
$(document).on('tap', 'button', function(ev) {
    var match = /^(category[0-9]+)-btn$/.exec(this.id);
    if (match) {
        ev.data = { category: match[1] };
        return onlineListGen.call(this, ev);
    }
    return true;
});
```

Not tested, but you should get the idea...